# Stackoverflow in recursive method to create hiearchy

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Suppose i have an image like this (the numbers are for explaining, so focus on the white): 
[image: example image]

I'm working on a method to create a hiearchy of the contours instead of a flat list. In the case of the image above:

```
-n1 holds 1 contour: n2 
-n2 hold 3 contours: n3, n4, n5 
-n5 holds 1 contour: n6 
-n6 holds 1 contour: n7
```

Make sure you understand the above before continue reading.

I have the method  addContainingBlob, this method is in the blob class. I already checked in another method if the blobToAdd is within the bounds of the blob where i add it. I get a `StackOverflowError` at this line: `b.addContainingBlob(blobToAdd); // <<<<<<`.

I'm breaking my head around this for the last hour. Can someone see why it goes wrong?

```
protected void addContainingBlob(Blob blobToAdd) {

    if (containingBlobs.size() == 0) {
        containingBlobs.add(blobToAdd);
        return;
    }

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
    r1.setBounds(blobToAdd.minX(), blobToAdd.minY(), blobToAdd.width(), blobToAdd.height());

    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();

    // first check if we already have a containing blob that
    // can hold the one we like to add
    for (Blob b : containingBlobs) {
        r2.setBounds(b.minX(), b.minY(), b.width(), b.height());

        if (r2.contains(r1)) {
            b.addContainingBlob(blobToAdd); // <<<<<<
            return;
        }

    }

    // it can also be that one OR MORE of the containing blobs can fit in the blob we like to add
    for (int i = containingBlobs.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Blob b = containingBlobs.get(i);
        r2.setBounds(b.minX(), b.minY(), b.width(), b.height());

        if (r1.contains(r2)) {
            containingBlobs.remove(i);
            blobToAdd.addContainingBlob(b);
        }

    }
    containingBlobs.add(blobToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible that a blob contains itself, causing an infinite récursive call ?

Comment: In the rest of the stack trace, are there any references to `blobToAdd.addContainingBlob(b);`?

Comment: In the second case, where none of the containingBlobs can hold the `blobToAdd` but the `blobToAdd` can hold some of the containingBlobs, you don't add the `blobToAdd` to the `containingBlobs`. Is that correct?

Comment: @MandarPandit This question got nothing to do with the recursion tag

Comment: @DSquare thanks, it is not the problem but it was indeed something i forgot :) I will edit my post above to fix that.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes! You are right. In another method i had for `if (i == j) continue;` i thought that was taking care of things but it only works for a depth of 0.
Thank you so much! If you drop it as an answer below then i drop the karma on you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code allows a blob to contains itself, the call to `blobToAdd.addContainingBlob(b)` will lead to infinite recursion because of

```
    if (r2.contains(r1)) {
        b.addContainingBlob(blobToAdd); // <<<<<<
        return;
    }
```